# iPhone NavBar with tintColor looks Flat

Tags: iphone, gradient, navbar, tintcolor

I am able to use tintColor to change the color of my NavBar, but this causes the NavBar to appear "flat". The standard NavBars have a shading to them - is there any way to accomplish this shading without using a custom image in place of the NavBar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the tint color you're using—bright colors often drown out the subtle gradients that the standard navigation bar applies. Interface Builder is the best place to try that out; you ought to be able to find a color close to the one you're after whose shading on the navigation bar will still look good.